# Как сделать текст с обводкой границ в CSS

Tags: html, css, css3

Я хотел сделать обводку уже имеющегося текста на чистом css, но столкнулся с проблемой позиционирования и создания обводки шрифта. Есть ли у вас идеи, как сделать это правильно сделать или популярный метод решения этого вопроса

[image: Вот как оно должно смотреться]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Есть как минимум 2 варианта, как сделать такую обводку текста с помощью:

- `-webkit-text-stroke`
- svg text

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 72px;
  font-family: 'Aerial', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  left: 2rem;
  color: white;
}

h1:before {
  content: attr(data-style);
  position: absolute;
  left: -1.5rem;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #ffffff50;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1 data-style="About Us">About Us</h1>

<svg viewbox="0 0 10 2">
  <text x="3" y="1" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1" font-weight="bold" fill="#fff" stroke-width=".015" font-family="Arial, sans-serif">ABOUT US</text>
  <text x="2.7" y="1" text-anchor="middle" font-size="1" font-weight="bold" fill="none" stroke-width=".015" stroke="#ffffff50" font-family="Arial, sans-serif">ABOUT US</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: И третий - text-shadow)

Comment: Благодарю, очень полезно было это узнать, спасли

Answer (score 6):

Пример

Для обводки текста [-webkit-text-stroke](https://caniuse.com/text-stroke), поддержка > 97%

```css
body {
  padding: 3rem;
  background-color: #000;
}

.heading {
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.heading__title {
  font-size: 8vw;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.heading__title--stroke {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -3vw;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  <h1 class="heading__title">About us</h1>
  <h1 class="heading__title heading__title--stroke">About us</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Почему-то думал, что у него плохая поддержка. Удивили)

Comment: Я придумал, как его применить без повтора текста в разметке.

Answer (score 4):

Не совсем оно, но без повтора текста, и на вид похоже:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: .25ch;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: .5em 2em;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: -1ch 0 2px black, -1ch 0 white;
}
```

```html
<h1>About us</h1>
```

Comment: Даа, точно что я хотел, благодарю

Comment: Что означает `2px` в `text-shadow`?

Comment: @Ростислав, blur. Это просто я его так нестандартно применил.

Comment: Спасибо, хороший способ.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать основной текст обведённым, а белый - тенью:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: .25ch;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  padding: .5em 1em;
}

@supports (-webkit-text-stroke: 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5)) {
  h1 {
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    text-shadow: 1ch 0 white;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>About us</h1>
```